# has anyone gotten mysql working on ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I upgraded to ubuntu 18.10 and when I installed mysql server and workstation, the workstation wouldn't connect. the service --status-all says that mysql is running. This was a clean install, and I installed it the same way on 18.04 which worked. My friend has the same issue from a clean install

Comment: have you tried running it on docker?

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu MySQL maintainer here. MySQL works fine in 18.10, so you must be doing something different to usual. Please see https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: "Give the programmer some credit for basic intelligence: if the program really didn't work at all, they would probably have noticed. Since they haven't noticed, it must be working for them. Therefore, either you are doing something differently from them, or your environment is different from theirs"

Comment: Upgraded from 16.x ubuntu to 18.10 and workbench is apparently still installed but now refuses to open.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of developers are facing some sort of [issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095327/ubuntu-18-10-not-a-worth-upgrade) after upgrading to `Ubuntu 18.10` including me. I would suggest either wait for the update when they fix the issues or downgrade to `Ubuntu 18.04`